# Laravel Package: Route:resource() don't pass the parameters

Tags: laravel, routes, package, resources

I'm creating a simple Laravel Role Manager Package.

This is my package/route file.
[image: package/route]

I can access to all my routes expect those with parameters.
This is my `route:list`

[image: route:list]

For the show, update, destroy and edit I have those empty {}, it's supposed be {role}.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Route resource expects a model to map routes for (that is the actual resource) passing nothing means no parameters, so pass the model (I assume `role`)

```php
Route::resource('role', 'RoleController');
```

And now you can remove the prefix

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! That resolved my problem I misunderstood the route:resource.

Comment: You're welcome, please consider accepting the answer if it solves the problem